# HMT Naming Similarity Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, associations, naming-conventions, has-many-through

I have two two models: `Company` and `CompanyType`. I need an association setup where a company can have and belong to many types. Based off the rails convention of naming join models I'm in sort've a bind. I can't name my join model `CompanyType` because that obviously exists. What do you do in these sort've situations?

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
end

class CompanyType < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not going to attach more stuff to it, you can skip creating the join model by defining a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :company_types
end

class CompanyType < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
end

# No join model needed
```

You still need a migration to create the table though. See: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many

If you need the join model, you can follow the method explained in the same document, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the link.